Docker login to ECR returns a timeout
I always managed to connect to my ECR repos prior to today. I create a new repo and I've been trying to docker login just like the push commands indicated:
aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-central-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin MY-ACCOUNT-ID.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com

which gives me:
Error response from daemon: Get "https://MY-ACCOUNT-ID.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

I have done aws configure before running this and Docker is running on my machine. Any help on this would be gladly appreciated as I can't figure out why it does not work.
Many thanks!

Are you behind a firewall that requires a proxy?

@Shawn actually I had to re-install docker to make it work
